# Values coming as a list at outside the text box. What's wrong I'm doing? I want that values come in the text box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am writing code for Autocomplete select box using ajax in codeigniter. Code is successfully executed but the problem is output is not coming as i want. I want list into the text box and output is coming outside the text box as a list. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
public function auto()
{  
    $country = $this->input->post('country');
    $this->load->model('m_details');
    $query = $this->m_details->get_auto($country);

    foreach($query->result() as $row)
         echo "<li>$row->country</li>"; 
}
```

Model:

```
public function get_auto($country)
{

   $this->load->database();
   $this->db->select('country');
   // $this->db->from('global_geo_country');
   $this->db->like('country', $country,'both');
   //$this->db->from('global_geo_country');
   return $this->db->get('global_geo_country');
 }
```

View:

```
function ajaxSearch()
{
      var input_data = $('#country').val();
      if (input_data.length === 0)
      {
          $('#suggestions').hide();
      }
      else
      {
            var post_data = {
                            'country': input_data,
                            '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
                             };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url();?>test/auto",
                data: post_data,
                success: function(data) {
                    // return success
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        $('#suggestions').show();
                        $('#autoSuggestionsList').addClass('auto_list');
                        $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="search">
 <input name="country" id="country" type="text" onkeyup="ajaxSearch();">
    <div id="suggestions">
        <div id="autoSuggestionsList">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

What should I do to display the output in the text box? Please guide me.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML too ?

Comment: Hi Adrian, I updated HTML code in question. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: What is the response coming through data ?

Comment: Hi, List of countries is coming through data but outside the text box. Thanks for the response.

Comment: u should provide style like the link u refered